# Hide a Current Button on ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a button for updating data in `ng-form`. This button only appear when some form input is changed. I done this with `$dirty`.

When the Update is clicked, I update the data. But I want to hide this button when it clicked.

I have an `ng-click` method on button click.

I tried to hide it like this :-

```
$(this).hide();
```

The above solutions doesn't work & i also want some solution which is not jquery based.

HTML

```
<button class="btn-small" ng-click="updateData('contactinformation')" ng-show="contactinformationform.$dirty">Update</button>
```

CODE

```
$scope.updateData = function (category) {
        switch (category) {
            case 'basicinformation':
                $scope.categorynewdata = $scope.data.basicinformation[0];
                break;
            case 'contactinformation':
                $scope.categorynewdata = $scope.data.contactinformation[0]
                break;                
        }

        var query = {               
            category: category
        };

        Patients.updateData().save(query).$promise.then(function (data) {
            alert('Data updated successfully..!');
        });

    }
```

Comment: Show the HTML and Angular scripts please.

Comment: @Anup Take a look at my answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ng-hide` in your button like this

Define scope variable (Like flag) so that you can decide when to hide/show button.

```
<button ng-click="btnClicked()" ng-hide="hideMe">Submit</button>
```

**Controller**

```
// Initialize hideMe variable
$scope.hideMe = false;

$scope.btnClicked = function() {
     /* your code */

     $scope.hideMe = true;
}
```

Comment: I have this code on button `ng-show="formname.$dirty"`

Answer (score 1):

You can Try like this

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NbHD5/)**

**html**

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="ArrayController">
    <form>
        <input type="text" ng-model="name" ng-change='flag=false' />: Name
        <br>
        <input type="text" ng-model="age" ng-change='flag=false' />: Age
        <br>
        <button class="btn-small" ng-click="updateData('contactinformation')" ng-hide='flag'>Update</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**script**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('ArrayController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Manu';
    $scope.age = '21';
    $scope.flag = true;
    $scope.updateData = function (value) {
        $scope.flag = true;
    }
});
```

Comment: the button hides....but when i again change some input in form...update button doesn't appear?

Comment: does the update button appears property for the second time in my working demo which is shown

Comment: sure it does...but its not with `$dirty` logic